# Amcl defaut scan topic?

Tags: navigation, laser, ros-indigo, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using amcl with a defaut topic scan and it keep telling me:
"No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for XXX seconds"

I have double check my topic scan and made an initial pose with RViz.
Thanks for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215506/amcl-defaut-scan-topic-?/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, the only question I see here is: "What is the amcl default topic?".

Answering this:
The default topic of `amcl` is `scan` (see the [ROS wikipage on amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) or the [sourcecode](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/indigo-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L103) for this).

If this is not the question, please be more specific, add a real question and the launch/config files. Otherwise, we cannot help at all.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0